# Why no 1:1 relationship between assignment and equality operators?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, equality-operator

In the following code example, because I compare two `std::map` objects, I am compelled to implement `MyId::operator==()`.

`MyId` is a simple class: basically a wrapper over an array. This made me wonder why an equality operator is mandated: why aren't we given a default bitwise comparator? After all, we are given a default assignment operator, which does a <strike>bitwise</strike> memberwise copy between objects.

I understand the difference between deep and shallow copies and the *need* for assignment and equality operators. My question is why is there not a default "bitwise equality check" when there is a default assignment?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

typedef int myid[ 3 ];

struct MyId
{
  myid id_;
  bool operator<( const struct MyId& other ) const { return this < &other; }
  bool operator==( const struct MyId& other ) const
  {
    return ( 0 == std::memcmp( id_, other.id_, sizeof( myid ) ));
  }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::map< MyId, int> map;
  MyId id = { 1, 2, 3 };
  map[ id ] = 5;

  std::map< MyId, int> map2;
  map2[ id ] = 5;

  // This forces implementation of MyId::operator==():
  std::cout << std::boolalpha <<( map == map2 ) << std::endl;

  MyId i1 = { 4, 5, 6 };
  MyId i2 = { 7, 8, 9 };

  // No required implementation of MyId::operator=():
  i1 = i2;

  return 0;
}
```

**Update**: Publicly corrected my brain-fart RE: bitwise vs. memberwise default assignment operator.

Comment: The assignment operator and copy constructor do memberwise copy - not bitwise copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After all, we are given a default assignment operator, which does a
>   bitwise copy between objects.

No it doesn't. On the contrary, the default copy-assignment operator is constructed in such way it copy-assigns each and every member of the object. Depending on how copy-assignment operators are implemented in the field types, the result might be far from just a bitwise copy.

Anyway, the default copy-assignment (or copy-construction, or move-assignment, or even destruction) behavior is designed in a way to fit common basic needs. Based on the language specification, it's available most of the times, but there are known situations when the language is uncertain about your semantics, and it requires explicit definitions for these.

The equality operator is different. The actual equality relation is not implied by the language syntax, but purely by the semantics. Compiler don't know how you see two instances of a class 'equal' - therefore it demands you to tell him.

Comment: " the default copy-assignment operator is constructed in such way it copy-assigns each and every member of the object" You're right. Brain-fart on my part.

Comment: @StoneThrow My point was not to point out your mistake, but I was actually answering your question :)

Comment: @iehrlick Understood, I was just embarrassed that I didn't remember that while I was posting my question. :)

Comment: So I guess you'll always get assignment for free because the default implementation is a memberwise copy, and any class is ultimately some assemblage of POD, and POD obviously have inbuilt assignment. So a copy between objects will recursively memberwise copy until reaching POD copy. So was it just a design decision the same could not be implemented for equality? Seems like it could have been.

Comment: @StoneThrow Well, you won't always get default copy-assignment for free. Copy-assignment operator might be either explicitly deleted or made private in one of "your" field types - in this case, "your" default copy-assignment will not be generated as well.

Comment: Good point - but that's more like explicitly hiding what is otherwise given for free. As opposed to my mythical default equality operator, which doesn't exist to begin with.

Comment: @StoneThrow Language designers (alongside with compiler developers) hate complexity, and they try to avoid it wherever possible. Bringing in a default compare operator might be technically possible in some implementation of some OO language... But then there's a reality. How to default-compare two objects of a class without any fields? How to default-compare two objects of different derived classes of a single base class - by their base reference? Should `mutable` fields be compared? And so on. This would bring a really nice big pile of complexity which C++ is full of by itself.